# Assigning elements to array based on position JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I went back to some of my previous task that I neglected because I thought they weren't interesting and I had a `reverseArray()` and a `reverseArrayInPlace()` function to create. The `reverseArray()` should return a new array that has the original reversed with the original one intact (basically, `A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `B = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`) while the `reverseArrayInPlace()` should take that A array, reverse its items and return A, basically A was `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and now is `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`. The one that returns a new array I've done using unshift and it was no problem. But the second one I've thought about doing it with assignment, basically:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
let temporary;
for (let i = 0; i<Math.floor((array.length)/2); i++) {
    temporary = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[length - 1 - i] = temporary;
}
return array;
}
```

I'm creating a temporary binding, assigning the first (and then second and so on until half the array is done) to it, then the last - i to the first etc. and then that last - i is assigned temporary. The problem is that the resulting array is `[5, 4, 3, 4, 5]`. In Chrome debugging I can see that instead of the last element becoming 1, the element on the -1 position becomes 1 ...

[chrome debugging console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zaIH.png)

Yes, I know that's not how you do it nowadays. But it was the simplest way I could think that fit the task requirements.

EDIT: I forgot to add the question)): how to do it so the A array becomes `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` with this method (or something similar)?

Comment: Do you happen to know about [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)?

Comment: I was not allowed to use reverse. I had to do it by hand.

Comment: `length` is not explicitly defined in the last assignment. That implicitly leads to `window.length - 1 - 0` which results in `-1` in the first iteration. Check out [`window.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length)

Comment: Basically I spent the last 5 minutes or so asking the question because I forgot to write the array. part and simply wrote length .... thanks a lot for pointing that out...

Comment: @LiviuGanea do you want the method with the same code or with a different code but the result is the same.?

Comment: @BathriNathan Lain and I already figured it out, I forgot to add array to "length" in the last assignment. But if you want and have nothing else to do, you can write with some different code with the same result. Thx.